# Pass an array of objects from a controller to an other one. Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I have an entity called Ticket.

In one of my controllers, I have an array or Tickets, that I would like to send to an other controller.

My first controller :

```
//some code...

return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('tracker_ticket_view', array(
            'TicketId' => $ticket->getId(),   
            'lticket'  => $lticket   //$lticket contains an array of tickets
        )));
```

My other controller :

```
@Route("/view/{TicketId}/{lticket}", 
 * defaults = { "lticket" = null},
 * name="tracker_ticket_view")
 * @ParamConverter("ticket", class="AtgpTrackerBundle:Ticket", options={"id" = "TicketId"})
 * @Template()
 */
public function viewAction(Ticket $ticket, Request $request, Array $lticket)
{    

//some code...
```

This code obviously gives me an Array to String exception. I guess lticket has to appear in the route, but symfony doesnt know what to type.

As I did here, we can send unique objects through controllers thanks to the Param Converter, but I dont know how to proceed with an array of object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of define a `/view/{TicketId}/{lticket}` route, pass the array to the query string.

```
/**
 * @Route("/view/{TicketId}", defaults = { "lticket" = null}, name="tracker_ticket_view")
 * @ParamConverter("ticket", class="AtgpTrackerBundle:Ticket", options={"id" = "TicketId"})
 * @Template()
 */
public function viewAction(Ticket $ticket, Request $request)
{
    $lticket = $request->query->get('lticket');
```